# Is there an algorithm to efficiently generate all partitions of a set such that no cell contains fewer than k elements of the set?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, partitions, clustering

I am trying to generate partitions of networks to evaluate clustering algorithms. I know that generating all partitions is infeasible (since they grow with Stirling number of the second kind which get big very quickly). I would like to restrict this to partitions that have a minimum size since these are the ones I care about anyway.

As a bonus, if anyone has a good way to estimate the number of such partitions for set size N, number of partitions k and minimum partition size l that would also be appreciated.

Comment: You can easility design such algorithms using [recursion/backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).

Comment: What is $k$?: Number of partitions or the minimum size of a cluster?